# How to get count of rows after tomorrow?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a SQLite database which has a table of tasks containing a column of dueDates. I want to filter out dates that are after tomorrow's date.

If tomorrow's date is April 29th, I should get the dates after tomorrow. I want to get the number of tasks that are after tomorrow.

For this I have converted the string into a date. The format is :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

dateToday  = calendar.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy");
dueDateToday = df.format(dateToday);

calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
dueTomorrow = calendar.getTime();

dueDateTomorrow = df.format(dueTomorrow);
```

and the query is:

```
public int getPendingTasksLaterDays(String tomorrow) {
    ArrayList<Task> conList = new ArrayList<Task>();


    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TASK_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_TASK_STATUS + " = 1" + " AND " + KEY_DUE_DATE + " > '" + tomorrow + "'" ;


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);

    if (mCount.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            count = mCount.getInt(0);
        } while (mCount.moveToNext());
    }

    Log.d("query",selectQuery);

    Log.d("count",String.valueOf(count));
    mCount.close();

    return count;
}
```

But the query is not working for me. The count I am getting is 0. 
What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: SQLite does not use `d MMM yyyy` as the DateFormat. Please see the Time Strings section in the [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your query can use the [`date`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) function in SQLite to find everything after tomorrow, but that assumes you have correctly stored your due date column at least in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. (Other formats are in the link).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tasks WHERE due_date > date('now', '+1 day');
```

If you don't store your dates correctly in the database, then, yes, you very likely will get 0 results.

It's also worth mentioning that you can get the number of results from a Cursor with the `getCount` method without needing `COUNT(*)`

```
int count = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null).getCount();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your query like this

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM " + TASK_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_TASK_STATUS + " = 1" + " AND " +
        KEY_DUE_DATE + " > '" + tomorrow + "'" ;
```

Comment: What's the change? @Nazmul Hasan Masum

Comment: yes used count function. I tried this but not getting any count in return its 0. May be date is not getting compared? how to compare this date? @Nazmul Hasan Masum